# Fourier Transform of $r^n e^{-\alpha r}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, fourier-transform

I believe I can solve this problem, but I would like some help deciphering what my professor is asking me to do. He is having us find the Fourier transform of 
\begin{equation}
r^n e^{-\alpha r}
\end{equation}
and says "find this in terms of $\alpha$ derivatives of the Fourier transform of part (i)". My result from part (i) is
\begin{equation}
f(r) = \dfrac{1}{r}e^{-\alpha r} \Rightarrow \tilde{f}(k) = -\dfrac{4\pi}{(\alpha + ik)^2}
\end{equation}
In that problem, he did explicitly ask us to evaluate part (i) in the limit of $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, which of course is just $\tilde{f}(k) = 4\pi / k^2$.

Any help in understanding what to do would be great. I know how to take the Fourier transforms, but I'm unsure what he is asking us to do with the $\alpha$ derivatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate your original Fourier transform
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\int d^3r\,\frac{e^{-\alpha r}}{r}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}=\int d^3r\,\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}e^{-\alpha r}}{r}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}=-\int d^3r\,e^{-\alpha r}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}=-\mathcal{F}\{e^{-\alpha r}\}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\frac{4\pi}{(\alpha+ik)^2}=\ldots$$
And similary for high order derivatives